Telerik kendo ui jquery grid
In the latest release of Telerik Kendo UI for jquery it has been written about the possibility to re-render particular row when using the grid widget. I know that when googling it is possible to find the kendoFastReDrawMethod, but there is no documentation about this new feature. Can someone help me?

Do you mean this item that is flagged as completed? Or the article from the docs? There is no documentation for the kendoFastReDraw as it is not a kendo method, but the implementation is a workaround, suggested by the SO user, noted in the end of the article.
To my knowledge, with the Feature Request item completed the widget(by default) will update only the edited item/row if the cell being edited is not part of any data operation i.e. filtering, sorting, grouping, etc. For example, if you have a grid with name and age columns, sorted by age, editing a cell in the name column will re-render only the edited row, but updating a cell in the age column will re-render the entire grid.

If you read the what’s new article you can read this “new” feature when they talk about the grid

I guess the statement is related to the item flagged as completed I linked above. Check this example - if you update any cell that is not in the sorted column the styled td element is preserved. If you update a cell in the sorted column the entire grid is re-rendered and the styled td element is refreshed and no longer styled. But all of this is happening internally, there is no new method exposed, to my knowledge, that would allow you to force a redraw of a specific row.
